# How to correlate an assigned String value to an Integer value?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I'm writing a code that allows the user to dictate what type of investment they want (Annual, Monthly or Quarterly) and each investment type correlates to a specific integer: i.e. Annual = 1, Monthly = 12, and Quarterly = 4. However when I assigned annual a value, I also need it to correlate to an int value in my investment equation below and am completely stumped on how to do so.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class CompoundInterest {

    public static void main (String [] args)
            { 
                Scanner cool = new Scanner (System.in);
    double saving, rate;
    int principal, years;
    int choice;

    System.out.println("Please enter you principal investment:");
    /*Print statment prompts user to enter their principal investment*/
    principal = cool.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Would you like to have a regular investment plan?");
    /* Print out statement asks user if they would like to participate in a regular investment plan*/
    String question =cool.next();

    System.out.println("What type of investment plan would you prefer (Annual, Quarterly, or Monthly)?");
    String quest =cool.next();

    while (quest.equalsIgnoreCase(("Annual"))) 
    {  String Annual="1";
        Annual.equals(choice);

     }

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of years that you wish to invest for:");
    /* Print statement prompts user to enter the number of years that they wish to invest for*/
    years = cool.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the return rate per year:");
    /* Print statement prompts user to enter the return rate per year*/
    rate = cool.nextDouble();

    saving = principal*(1+(rate/choice))* Math.pow(choice, years);
    System.out.printf("%.2f", saving);
    }
```

Comment: You can create an array "invesment" with positions Annual, Monthly and Quarterly so that invesment[Integer.parseInt(Annual)] = your_correlated_value;

Answer (score 1):

- Once the type of investment plan is answered, you need to check if the `quest` variable matches any of the string you are expecting, i.e., `Annual`, `Quarterly`, or `Monthly`.
- If the `quest` matches any of the choices, you assign a correct value to the `choice` variable, i.e., 1, 4, or 12.
- You also may also need to think of situations if the answer doesn't match any of the correct choices.

  ```
  if ("Annual".equalsIgnoreCase(quest)) {
      choice = 1;
  } else if ("Quarterly".equalsIgnoreCase(quest)) {
      choice = 4;
  } else if ("Monthly".equalsIgnoreCase(quest)) {
      choice = 12;
  } else {
      //you need to do something here.
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an enum that defines the int you want.  I'll call the enum Plan and the int term:

```
public enum Plan {
    ANNUAL(1),
    QUARTERLY(4),
    MONTHLY(12);

    int term;

    Plan(int term) {
        this.term = term;
    }
};
```

You would use this in your code like this (this replaces int choice):

```
    Plan plan = Plan.valueOf(quest.toUpperCase());
    saving = principal * (1 + (rate / plan.term)) * Math.pow(plan.term, years);
```

I think you are going to need different versions of your calculation.  The enum approach would support this easily if you added a method to the enum that switches on the value of the enum.  You can work out the different implementations of the calculation and define them in the case statements.

```
    double calculateSavings(int principal, double rate, int years) {
        switch (this) {
            case ANNUAL:
            case QUARTERLY:
            case MONTHLY:
            default:
                return principal * (1 + (rate / term)) * Math.pow(term, years);
        }
    }
```

If you go this route you would use it in your code like this:

```
    // saving = principal * (1 + (rate / plan.term)) * Math.pow(plan.term, years);
    saving = plan.calculateSavings(principal, rate,years);
```